# Can mono be used to with assemblies 3rd party assemblies that have been obfuscated

Tags: c#, .net, mono, obfuscation

I downloaded and I am trying to use the MOMA but when I start the analyze process on a third party dll, the Analyzer throws an array out of bounds exception. Looking at the call stack (and doing a lot of guess) it seems that it is having trouble with the obfuscation of the dll.. Upon searching I see several people talking about having trouble with Mono and obfuscation, but I don't can't seem to find any direct solutions or statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

Some obfuscation techniques do not work on Mono (they rely on implementation details of Microsoft's .NET implementation). Other obfuscation techniques (which follow the IL documentation) work just fine.

Your best choice is to try it out and see what happens (or turn off obfuscation altogether).